# how to convert this code to insert it in .js file

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm trying to make my website multilingual, i have the **php** code also and i have translated files, but my site has also **js** file where is this words which i want to translate, there is example of this php code and how to insert it to **js** file?

There is JS code

```
// Update search list
                rsParent.html($('<div>').attr({id: 'relatedSearches', class: 'contentBox'})
                    .append($('<div>').addClass('cbHead').text('Related Searches'))
                    .append($('<div>').addClass('cbBody').html(list)));
            }
        });
```

and the word "Related Searches" i want to replace with this php code

```
<?php echo $lang['CHARTS']; ?>
```

Comment: use inline js fragment within php page to insert/output php code into javascript code

Comment: yes but how to make like this?

Comment: you said "i have the php code", how does it look like?

Comment: <?php echo $lang['CHARTS']; ?>

this is code which i want to insert

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do it directly since PHP is a serverside language which is executed once on a webserver, unlike javascript that is executed in client's browser.

What you can do is encode your PHP array **$lang** to **JSON** and then output it as inline javascript and assign it to a variable in javascript.

```
<?php
echo "<script>";
echo "var lang = " . JSON_encode($lang) . ";";
echo "</script>";
?>
```

Make sure this php code is placed (executed) before your javascript file because variable **lang** has to be declared before your javascript is executed.

Comment: please make an example, put this code in my js code where is Related Searches